# Factorial digit sum in APL (Project Euler 20)

Tags: math, digits, largenumber, apl

First I found `+/⍎¨⍕(!8)` and it gave me the result 9. But if I do `100!`, as the number is big, I am not able to get that.

With `⍎¨⍕(!100)` I am getting a syntax error: `⍎SYNTAX ERROR`

Is there any other way to solve the problem or can you suggest me some modifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

!100 is a large number and when you format it's result you'll get a string representing a number in E notation.

`⍕!100` → `'9.332621544E157'`, when you attempted to eval (`⍎`) each character you ran into a syntax error since E has no meaning.

There are two ways to split a large integer into it's digits:

Firstly with inverse decode, examples can be found on the [APLcart](https://aplcart.info/?q=%E2%8A%A5%E2%8D%A3%C2%AF1#)

```
    10⊥⍣¯1!100
```

This is vulnerable to floating point imprecision, however.

The second and preferred option is using big from the dfns library, which can be imported using the quad function `CY`.

`'big'⎕CY'dfns'`

Examples [here](https://dfns.dyalog.com/n_big.htm)

And thankfully the last example covers your exact case! Factorial 100 is `↑×big/⍳100`

The final solution to the problem could look like this:

`+/⍎¨↑×big/⍳100`

Comment: Maybe show how to import the `big` operator, and maybe even how to compute the final sum using it?

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///Xz0pM139Ud9U50j1lLS8YnUuIPtR2wQFbf1HvX2HVjxqm3h4OlAJkLfZ0MDg/38A "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")